# attach some value with url while fetching data in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

The situation is that there is a select dropdown from which when we select an item, that item value gets attached with url and the data fetched is displayed in form of a Table.The table changes as per the selected option.
I have to implement it using backbone.the code goes like this

```
HTML:
<select id="pu">
<option val=0>mbs</option>
<option val=1>mfs</option>
<option val=2>all</option>
</select>

backbone code:
var bomRecordModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var bomRecordCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : bomRecordModel,
        ->>>    url: "/easybom/easybom?opcode=6&pu_id=",
             parse: function(response){
                    return response.aaData;
                }
});
brcObject =  new bomRecordCollection();
brcObject.fetch();
```

How to attach the selected pu to pu_id of  url??? I m storing selected value as cookie ie. $.cookie("pu"). i tried doing but itz not working 
url: "/easybom/easybom?opcode=6&pu_id="+$.cookie("pu"),

kindly help. I m new to backbone.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: function () {
    return "/easybom/easybom?opcode=6&pu_id=" + $("#pu option:selected").attr('val');
}
```

Comment: Thank you jgillich.but how about if I select another option, the url should fetch and the table needs to re-render ?? how to do